# Python statement uses excessive amounts of RAM

Tags: python, memory-management

This simple statement:

```
zip(xrange(0, 11614321), xrange(0, 11627964))
```

...is eating most of my RAM. (>150 MiB!) Why?

**Edit:** Ah, re-reading the docs, I see `zip` returns a list, not an iterable. Anything like `zip` that returns an iterable?

---

The larger picture: I'm iterating over two large arrays of file data, and I'm doing things like iterating (0-end, 0-end), (0-end, 1-end), etc. I'd like to not slice the array, as it would cause excessive allocations of memory. I figured I'd just iterate over the indexes instead, but that doesn't seem to work, as per above. The whole code:

```
def subsequence_length(data_a, data_b, loc_a, loc_b):
    length = 0
    for i_a, i_b in zip(xrange(loc_a, len(data_a)), xrange(loc_b, len(data_b))):
        if data_a[i_a] == data_b[i_b]:
            length += 1
        else:
            break
    return length
```

Comment: @erjang: SO requires you to wait a set time period before you can accept an answer. Now that that period has expired, I've accepted nos's answer. Of my other questions, I got though them every now an then: the ones that don't have accepted answers don't because nobody has answered the question satisfactorily.

Comment: What computer & OS combo are you using that only has 150 MiB of RAM?

Comment: @martineau: It's a Linux laptop, with 2 GiB of RAM. That's not the point. Something that just increments two integers in lockstep should not need even a kilobyte, let alone 150 MiB. (150 MiB is how much it used & I could measure before I killed it. That particular statement was actually eating *all* of my RAM.)

Comment: Thanks. I just replicated the issue on one of my old desktops with about 500 MB of free RAM and at one point it used *all* but 1 MB of it. Weird, you shouldn't need to use `izip` or roll your own generator to do this...even if it would be a lot more resource friendly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from itertools

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you didn't want to use the `itertools` module, it would be trivial to write your own iterator that did the same thing, at least if you know you're dealing with exactly two input iterators.

```
def xzip2(i1, i2):
    i1, i2 = iter(i1), iter(i2)
    while True:
        yield next(i1), next(i2)
```

Actually, upon further reflection, it is not that hard to make it work with any number of iterators. I am fairly sure `itertools.izip` must be implemented something like this.

```
def xzip(*iters):
    iters = [iter(i) for i in iters]
    while True:
        yield tuple([next(i) for i in iters])
```

(And looking at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), I see it is, except they're using `map` rather than list comprehensions.)

Comment: You should use the builtin `next` function (`next(i1)`), the method has been renamed `__next__` in Python 3.

Comment: And you should do `i1 = iter(i1); i2 = iter(i2)` before looping. `xrange` is iterable, but not itself an iterator.

Comment: Good suggestions both. Added.